# Returning items from DynamoDB in Terraform as a Data Source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb

I want to return items which are being held in DynamoDB using Terraform.  This data source will then be used to construct a Tagging Policy

I want to hold cost centre numbers in DynamoDB, to the help construct Tagging Policies

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "poc" {
  name         = "poc"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "tag_key"
  range_key    = "tag_value"

  attribute {
    name = "tag_key"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "tag_value"
    type = "S"
  }


  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = false
  }
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "poc1" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.poc.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.poc.hash_key
  range_key  = aws_dynamodb_table.poc.range_key  
  depends_on = [aws_dynamodb_table.poc]

  item = <<ITEM
{
  "tag_key": {
    "S": "CostCenter"
  },
  "tag_value": {
    "S": "1111"
  }
}
ITEM
}
```

I can build the dynamoDB and upload some data to it.

```
data "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "poc" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.poc.name
  key                   = <<KEY
{
    "tag_key": {"S": "CostCenter"}
}
KEY
  depends_on            = [aws_dynamodb_table_item.poc]
}
```

But i am struggling to get the "key" right for the data source.  For the Primary key i am using both Partition key and sort key.  But i am struggling with the syntax needed in the data source.

Is anyone able to help point out my error?

```
│ Error: reading Amazon DynamoDB Table Item Data Source (poc|tag_key||CostCenter|): ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

I basically want to list all the items which have "CostCenter" as Partition key as the data source

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must [provide the sort key as well](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/dynamodb_table_item#key):

> For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

If you want a list of items maybe you could use a `for_each`.

This is an example that worked for me (please note that `aws_dynamodb_table` and `aws_dynamodb_table_item` resources are the same from your example):

```
data "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "poc" {
  for_each = toset(local.tag_values)

  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.poc.name
  key        = <<KEY
{
    "tag_key": {"S": "CostCenter"},
    "tag_value": {"S": "${each.key}"}
}
KEY
  depends_on = [aws_dynamodb_table_item.poc]
}

output "items" {
  value = [
    for item in data.aws_dynamodb_table_item.poc : jsondecode(item.item)
  ]
}

locals {
  tag_values = ["1111"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/dynamodb_table_item):

> `key` - (Required) A map of attribute names to AttributeValue objects, representing the primary key of the item to retrieve. For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

You've defined a range (sort) key on your table, so your table's primary key is a composite of the hash key and the range (sort) key. You will have to provide both values in order to the `aws_dynamodb_table_item` datasource in order to retrieve the item.